# API - is the connection secure?

Tags: php, api

How to check if a connection to a REST API is secure?

1) I'm building an API and want to make sure that the connection is running SSL before the response is generated and returned to the client.. Username and password is passed in every request

2) And how can you make a fsockopen connection with SSL?

```
$this->url = 'api.domain.com';
$this->path = '/v1/json/account/user/pass/?id=123';

if($this->fp = fsockopen($this->url, $this->port, $errno, $errstr, $this->timeout)){
    $write = "$this->method $this->path HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $write .= "Host: $this->url\r\n";
    $write .= "Content-Type: $this->content_type\r\n";
    $write .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

    fwrite($this->fp, $write);

    while($line = fgets($this->fp)){
        if($line !== false) $this->response .= $line;
    }

    fclose($this->fp);
}
```

Comment: Well, what kind of API? How are you connecting to it? Please add more detail to the question.

Comment: how to make a SSL connection with fsockopen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check `$_SERVER['HTTPS']`.

The PHP manual at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php says:

> 'HTTPS'
>
> Set to a non-empty value if the script was queried through the HTTPS protocol.
>
> Note: Note that when using ISAPI with IIS, the value will be off if the request was not made   > through the HTTPS protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. You can even force it to be. HTTP works on port 80 and HTTPS on 443. You can discard all traffic not comming from 443.