# How to verify HTTP Request via API is secure?

Tags: rest, api, security, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am using Apex (Force.com) to send HTTP requests to a server that is hosted on AWS. How can I know if the server I am sending the HTTP request is using a valid certificate and my request will be encrypted before being sent out? I know I'd be able to look for the lock icon on the browser but since this is a RESTful API callout, I'm not sure how to do that. I found one similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6546629/api-is-the-connection-secure) and the answer seems to be PHP specific.

Answer (score 0):

Message Analyzer Tool would help you here and this tool will track all communication including encryption.

Please install Message Analyzer tool in your client OR server environment and track the message.

Please check this link - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn727244.aspx

[image]

Regards

Abdul